# Restlet : why can't I get the POSTed XML content?

Tags: xml, resources, entity, restlet

I'm using [restlet](http://restlet.org/learn/javadocs/2.1/jse/api/) to provide REST services through an API. Until now, all available resources have been accepting content in the form of key,value pairs. I'm now about to extend this so that some resources may accept XML instead.

However, I can't get that to work. When i POST requests with XML content, the `Request#getEntity()` doesn't seem to have any idea of the posted content. I've tried to wrap the entity in a `DomRepresentation`, but that doesn't do anything either. Also, when i invoke `Request#getEntity().getText()` all i get back is a **null**.

What do I need to do in order to get my service to accept XML? I've added `org.restlet.ext.xml` to the classpath...do I need to declare this in some way? Furthermore, are there any other dependencies which I somehow need to take care of manually?

Comment: We need to see your resource code to help.  Also the doe that's making the request.

Comment: This should definitely work. Aren't you consuming the request entity already before calling getText() again, such as in a filter?

Answer (score 0):

Try using s StringRepresentation.
see this: http://l46kok.blogspot.co.il/2013/06/restlet-how-to-post-xml-data-from-client.html